# BIOS doesn't let me change Boot priority

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, bios

I have an Insys M74T with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS installed and I want to install Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon over it using a bootable Pen Drive.

I already did the bootable USB with Mint OS, however, when I try to change the Boot Priority in Phoenix SecureCore BIOS so I can boot the computer by the USB it won't let me. It keeps sounding 'beeps' but won't change the order. I've already tried with '+', '-', 'F6' and 'Space' keys and also using "Shift" with the same keys but nothing happens.

As you can see in the photo the USB appears in 4th place and I need to move it to the 1st place so the computer will boot through it: https://ibb.co/34x9k0F

However, no matter wich keys I press, the order of Boot priority devices won't move. The computer just keeps sounding "beep" and nothing more happens.

Did someone have this problem already or know how to solve it?

Comment: You don't have a US keyboard, try `?` and `shift + »` for `-/+` (the keys between `0` and `backspace`).

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thank you very much for the info!

Answer (score 0):

As the user Freddy said:

> You don't have a US keyboard, try ? and shift + » for -/+ (the keys between 0 and backspace).

This resolved my problem!